# Proof by Contradiction - Infinite set of Binary 1s

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A binary string is any sequence of zeros and ones. Let $A$ be the set of binary strings
having only $1’s$. In other words, $A = \{1, 11, 111, 1111, . . .\}$. Prove by contradiction that A is
of infinite size. That is, prove by contradiction: $P: ∄n ∈ N, |A| = n$.

Can someone tell me if I’m even remotely close to the right answer? I’m bad with proofs.

My work so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA586.jpg

Comment: Please don't use image to show the bulk of your post.  Instead, please type out the contents of the image as you have done with the problem statement, that is, with proper Mathjax formatting. Images are supposed to be reserved for certain diagrams or statistical datum which could not be communicated effectively with plain text nor expressions supported by MathJax.

Comment: Any explanation on $\lvert p\rvert > \lvert q\rvert$ or $\lvert 111\rvert > \lvert 1111\rvert$?

Answer (score 0):

**Claim:** A has a bijection with ℕ. Define a function f : A ⭢ ℕ such that f(x) is the length of x, and a function g: ℕ ⭢ A such that g(n) is 1....1 (n many times). You could also define the second function by induction.

Given some more formality, you could also think of A as certain strings, which are typically implemented such that there is an operation ++ (concatenation). Such a function would allow for a more concrete definition of f in the above.

The claim allows us to rephrase your question:

> Demonstrate using argument by contradiction that the cardinality of ℕ is not finite

Suppose for a contradiction that the cardinality of ℕ is finite, and let b : {1,....,n} ↔ ℕ be a bijection. Then we can consider l := max {b(k) : 1 ≤k ≤ n}, and l+1. l+1 is a natural number, and so there must be k : ℕ such that 1 ≤ k ≤ n and b(k) = l + 1, so that l ≤ b(k) = l+1, a contradiction.

Comment: Reminder: Please use MathJax!